# if $a$ is a solution of any congruence modulo $p$, then $a + np$ also a solution for any $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Where does the statement in the title come from?

I tried this below:

$ya \equiv x \pmod p$

$p \mid ya - x$

$pq = ya - x$

$pq + ya = x$

Am I close?

Comment: Now try to show that $y(a+np)\equiv x\pmod{p}$.

Comment: Since $p \mid ynp$ and $p \mid (ya - x)$, then $p \mid (ya - x + ynp)$?

Comment: @user273143 yes,because if $ynp$ and $(ya-x)$ are multiple of $p$ then convince yourself that $ya-x+ynp$ is also a multiple of $p$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note $ya=x \mod{p}$ if and only if $p|(ya-x)$.

Now let $n$ be an integer. Then $y(a+np)-x=ya+ynp-x=(ya-x)+ynp$. Now we know $p$ divides $ya-x$ from above and we can see that $p$ divides $ynp$ so it must divide the sum $(ya-x)+ynp$.

Then from the definition above this means $y(a+np)=x \mod{p}$ and hence $a+np$ is also a solution for any integer $n$.

Comment: Great stuff. Thanks.

Comment: @user273143 IMO,the great way to thanks someone on MSE is to upvote/accept the answer.

Comment: @ Arpit Kansal, I am not allowed to vote as I am not registered. I am waiting for the allotted time to pass so that I can choose Matt B's answer.